# Socket.io User Sessions With Redis and JWT

Tags: express, redis, socket.io

Could anyone please help me understand a this part of code:

```
  var auth = function(cb) {
return _.wrap(cb, function(fn, data) {
  redis.get(email, function(err, id){
    if (!err) throw err;
    if (!id) return socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
    fn(data);
   });
 });
};
```

that I got from this [article](http://www.codedevlog.com/blog/2014/10/23/socket-dot-io-user-sessions-with-redis-and-json-web-tokens/).

I don't understand what's happening there, even though I navigated to the lodash documentation and read about 'wrap' method. I'm confused, especially because I can't see where in the article this 'auth' is further used! (I think that is defined to be used somewhere after all).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's break that down. First, we are assigning a function that takes a `cb` parameter to `auth`. What does that function do, well, it returns the result of `_.wrap`. Looking at the docs, `_.wrap` is a currying function, so it takes an arg (`cb`) and a function, and returns a new function where the first parameter is bound to the arg, and the rest of the parameters are unbound. In fact, the `_.wrap` part:

```
return _.wrap(cb, function(fn, data) {
  /* code */
  fn(data); // inside of the redis scope
})
```

is probably overkill, since you are in a closure from the outer function, so you could just do:

```
return function(data) {
  /* code */
  cb(data) // in the redis callbak scope, but that is still in the closed over scope
}
```

I'm honestly not sure why they didn't just do that (hammer/nail?).

Let's go on.

So, we've determined that `auth` is a function that takes a `cb` parameter and returns a function that takes a `data` parameter. That function is now calling `redis.get` to find the value associated with the key stored in `email` (which is pulled in from the surrounding scope). It then calls the passed in callback function (the one taking an err and id) validates the parameters (disconnecting the websocket if the email isn't associated in redis, and finally calls the orginal `cb` callback with the passed in `data` parameter.

I'm not sure where it is used in the code, but the idea is that you can call it as:

```
let authCb = auth((data) => { console.log(data) })
authCb('test')
```

and if the email is found in redis, then `test` should be logged to the console. In the context of the article, you would use this to validate the connection before you actually started communicating with the socket (in the `cb` function)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain "it takes an arg (cb) and a function, and returns a new function where the first parameter is bound to the arg, and the rest of the parameters are unbound" more? Or if possible, point me to some example? I got closer, in fact I understand most of your response, specially the final idea (because it is clearly specified), but still don't understand why this "var auth" is defined, but never used! If you too don't see it, I leave it as "perhaps a mistake in the article". The general idea is now clear.

Comment: So in the example code in that article, same code block as the auth function, line 24 it starts getting used. Hope that helps

Comment: It was the only thing in that article I didn't ever read! Being used to socket.on(...), I just skipped over that and missed that auth is used, which raised the question, thank you, finally got it!